# Postman (JSON) - How do I put two environment variables into one?

Tags: json, environment-variables, postman

I have two variables and I'm trying to perform a calculation and store it in another environment variable.

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.clearEnvironmentVariable("AcceptQty");
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("AcceptQty", data.oi[0].roq);
postman.clearEnvironmentVariable("CancelQty");
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("CancelQty", data.oi[0].rocq); 
postman.clearEnvironmentVariable("TotalQty");
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("TotalQty", (AcceptQty - CancelQty));
```

It gives an error "ReferenceError: AcceptQty is not defined." Is it possible to put the two variables together like this or do I have to find a workaround? I know this seems like an easy workaround, but I have a TON of calculations like this so I'd rather not type any more than I need to.

This is the response to the request:

```
{
    "other_stuff": "NOT IMPORTANT",
    "order_items": [
        {
            "other_stuff": "NOT IMPORTANT",
            "roq": 1,
            "rocq": 0,
        }
    ]
}
```

I figured it out by looking at some of the examples that they had on www.getpostman.com. I completely missed the part where "data" was a keyword in Postman. Also, I used this code to finally set TotalQty.

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("TotalQty", (postman.getEnvironmentVariable("AcceptQty") - 
    postman.getEnvironmentVariable("CancelQty")));
```

Comment: Did you define the variables anywhere outside the posted snippet?

Comment: No. I did not. Also I realized I was wrong. I took out the TotalQty lines and the same error still popped up. I worked on this yesterday so I didn't remember exactly what the problem was.

Comment: So, to recap: the error tells you that a variable is not defined, and obviously, you did not define the variable.... sounds like a easy solution :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little new to this API stuff so what you "obviously" see, isn't exactly obvious to me. But I did figure out what the problem was.